# How can I test the importance of column order in indexing in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I'm reading Markus Winand's slides: https://www.slideshare.net/MarkusWinand/indexes-neglectedperformanceallrounder
[image]
I tested this by the steps below:

1. create a table with column_1 integer and column_2 integer
2. run the commands below:

```
INSERT INTO dev.table_name(column_1, column_2)
SELECT RANDOM() * 10, RANDOM() * 10 FROM generate_series(1, 10000);

create index idx on dev.table_name(column_1, column_2);

explain (buffers, analyze, verbose) select * from dev.table_name where column_2=2;

explain (buffers, analyze, verbose) select * from dev.table_name where column_1=2;

explain (buffers, analyze, verbose) select * from dev.table_name where column_1=2 and column_2= 2;
```

However, query for column_1 and column_2 use both index only scan instead of column_1 use index and column_2 use sequential scan as expected from the slides
[image]

My question is how am I able to test the importance of column order? Does this not work because I use integer columns? I tried deleting the cache using `sync && sudo purge` as well as `discard all`, but it is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes are good for finding needles in a haystack. They are not so spectacular at finding needles in a pin cushion.

You should make the conditions more selective, as well as make the table larger.

```
INSERT INTO dev.table_name(column_1, column_2)
SELECT RANDOM() * 1000, RANDOM() * 1000 FROM generate_series(1, 1000000);
```

Comment: thanks it works.. i have another qn, is this the conclusion? if i have 3 queries (where a = ? and b = ?, where a = ?, where b = ?) does it mean i need to use 2 indexes (a,b) and (b,a)?

Comment: There is no reason to have `(b,a)` rather than just `(b)` for your b-leading index, unless it enables an index-only scan (which it will here since your table only has two columns, but it is less likely to with more realistic tables with more columns).  Including the extra column is unlikely to do very much harm, but if you are trying to optimize everything to the highest degree it should be avoided.